# Meta-annotations for JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am not finding any meta-annotation facility for JPA. Any way to define a custom annotation that works as an sterotype (something like):

`@MyCustomAnnotation` on a field, equaling:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="foo",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="foobar", referencedColumnName = "bar", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false) )
@MapKeyColumn(name = "bla")
@Column(name = "bla")
```

Comment: Unfortunately not; meta-annotations (besides `@Inherited`) are implemented in framework software, such as Spring. Groovy has annotation collectors, though.

Comment: how would you expect a JPA provider to know *what* one of these annotations means? or indeed which ones to check for?

Comment: I don't know, that is why I ask if JPA provides any mechanism for such a need